# Can LM-fonts be used in "Regular Math" encoding with csplain?

Tags: csplain, enctex

Processing the following input with `csplain` prints "ec-lmr10":

```
\input t1code \input utf8lat1 \frlang \input lmfonts
\message{\fontname\tenrm}
\end
```

Is it possible to change this example so that "rm-lmr10" will be printed instead?

Comment: You're asking for T1 encoded fonts, so `ec-lmr10` is the choice; `\fontname` returns the name of the TFM file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lmfonts.tex` we find

```
\ismacro\fotenc{8t}\iftrue \def\ffnamepre{ec-}\fi      % T1 aka Cork
```

In `cs-heros.tex` we find

```
Encodings
---------

You can declare more cases for various text font encondings. User can define
font encoding by \def\fotenc{something}. Note \fotenc, no \fontenc. The
sequence \fotenc means "FOnt Text ENCoding".

The ff-mac.tex keeps the \fotenc macro unchanged, but if it is not defined then it does:

- \def\fotenc{8z} if CSplain is used without \input t1code nor \input ucode
- \def\fotenc{8t} if \input t1code or pdfTeX without CSplain is used
- \def\fotenc{U}  if \input ucode or XeTeX or LuaTeX is used
```

So when `t1code.tex` is loaded, the `ec-lm???` fonts will be used: accents (and not only them) would print wrong if the `rm-lm???` fonts are used.

Since `\fontname<font>` returns the name of the TFM file corresponding to the `<font>` selector, you get `ec-lmr10` as expected.